# Error in is.factor(x) : object 'x' not found when 'x' is in original file

Tags: r, anova

I am a new learner in R and am trying to create a ANOVA analysis by getting data from a .csv file, my initial code are as below:-

```
aovdata <- read.table ("Ritalin-by-condition.csv", header = T)
attach (aovdata)

Treatment <- as.factor(Treatment) ; Condition <- as.factor(Condition)
```

The console then prompt the below answer:-

```
Error in is.factor(x) : object 'Treatment' not found
```

I have checked the .csv file which contains the category 'Treatment' and 'Condition' .

Can you please let me know what I have done wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: Hello Spybuster, please do the following: run `aovdata <- read.table ("Ritalin-by-condition.csv", header = T)`,  then run `dput(aovdata[1:10,])`, copy the output, edit this post and paste the copied code using the code option.

Comment: hi @RicVillalba . Thank you for the tip and I'm completely new to stackoverflow.

I have run your suggested command, and the console prompted

```
> dput(avodata[1:10,])
Error in dput(avodata[1:10, ]) : object 'avodata' not found
```
it's very strange indeed

Comment: Did you run `aovdata <- read.table ("Ritalin-by-condition.csv", header = T)` first?

Comment: ok I got it now, but now when i run the Treatment command again, it gives the same response i.e. treatment not found

Comment: run `dput(aovdata[1:10,])` and paste so i can see what the problme could be

Comment: `> dput(aovdata[1:10,])

c("Placebo,Nonhyp,50", "Placebo,Nonhyp,45", "Placebo,Nonhyp,55", 
"Placebo,Nonhyp,52", "Ritalin,Nonhyp,67", "Ritalin,Nonhyp,60", 
"Ritalin,Nonhyp,58", "Ritalin,Nonhyp,65", "Placebo,Hypera,70", 
"Placebo,Hypera,72")`

is this ok

Comment: try `read.csv()` instead of `read.table()` ...  (once that's working -- it's **highly** recommended to transform variables *within* data frames and use the `data=` argument to statistical fitting functions rather than using `attach()` ...)

Comment: @BenBolker hi Ben, thank you for your suggestion. I got it now with read.csv . thanks!